# Not able to send mail to DL contacts using sendgrid

Tags: twilio, sendgrid, twilio-api, sendgrid-api-v3

Below is my code code which is I'm trying to send mail to DL contacts but the recipients are not receiving any mail but i can see 202 HTTP response once i send it but it works if i send mail to 1 contact

```
func main() {
    from := mail.NewEmail("test DL mail sending with sendgrid", "noreply@abc.com")
    subject := "test DL mail sending with sendgrid"
    to := mail.NewEmail("Example User", "Dkd-dev-team@abc.com")
    plainTextContent := "test DL mail sending with sendgrid"
    htmlContent := "<strong>test DL mail sending with sendgrid</strong>"
    message := mail.NewSingleEmail(from, subject, to, plainTextContent, htmlContent)
    client := sendgrid.NewSendClient("key")
    response, err := client.Send(message)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(response.StatusCode)
        fmt.Println(response.Body)
        fmt.Println(response.Headers)
    }
}
```